# Advice Rudin PMA

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I'm currently working through Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

My background consists of mainly working through most of Apostol's *Caluculus* Vol. 1, Velleman's *How to Prove it*, Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*, dabbling with Ross' *Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus*, and am concurrently attempting Bartle and Sherbert's *Introduction to Real Analysis* and Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  I switch back and forth between Lang's *Calculus of Several Variables* and the analysis texts.

I am having issues with the problems in Rudin's text in chapter one. I have read the chapter repeatedly as well as basically written it in my own words, I feel like I understand the material but then the problems manifest a barrier. Is it entirely necessary for me in order to progress to the next problem set to have completed the prior set?

Comment: Not really, but I must say that many ideas are basically introduced in the exercises. The definition of the exponential starting from integer exponents is there. Improper integrals are introduced there with probably many ideas related to them. I only realized this later into the book. You can look up solutions if you get absolutely stuck (for more than a day on a single exercise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not necessary. If this was the text for a course, most professors wouldn't assign all the problems. On the other hand, I have worked through all the problems in that set, aoI might be able to help answer your questions. Feel free to email me. My address is on my profile.